# Plot multiple solutions

Tags: plotting, color, legending, code-review

I want to plot multiple solutions of an equation, so that one can differ them in the plot.

The given equation is e.g.

```
sol = Solve[3 y^2 == x^3 + 7 x^2 + x, {x, y}]

Out: {{y -> -((Sqrt[x] Sqrt[1 + 7 x + x^2])/Sqrt[3])}, {y -> (
       Sqrt[x] Sqrt[1 + 7 x + x^2])/Sqrt[3]}}
```

Now I have 3 ways to plot the result.

The first one shows them in different colors with legend, but I dont like it, because I have to enter both solutions separately in the plot command:

```
Plot[{y /. sol[[1]], y /. sol[[2]]}, {x, -10, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Second command is very short, but shows both solutions in one color without legend. So it could be there is only one solution:

```
Plot[y /. # & /@ sol, {x, -10, 10}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The third needs no manual manipulation and shows both solution with an own color:

```
Module[{res = y /. # & /@ sol},
 Plot[res, {x, -10, 10}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
 ]
```

[image]

But for getting better with `Mathematica`, is there another/better/smarter way?

Comment: @YvesKlett I agree mikuszefski's answer is a duplicate to this. But I was asking for more/smarter ways doing this. If in the end this should be the best way, yes then it's a duplicate.

Comment: Hmmm, seems pretty neat to me already - what would you be expecting in terms of "smarter"? In fact you can make it even shorter (no need for mapping): `Plot[{Evaluate[y /. sol]}, {x, -10, 10}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]`, but I guess it will not get much better than that ;-)

Comment: @YvesKlett You see ...there's always a way doing things better, shorter or smarter :-)

Comment: Phab, glad you like it! I hope you do not mind the closure - in any case you could edit the question to differentiate it a bit more and nominate it for re-opening.

Answer (score 3):

Your second solution can be improved by `Evaluate[]` on the first plot argument.

```
Plot[Evaluate[y /. sol], {x, -10, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: I didnt hit on it ... nice! I added code and resulting plot.

Comment: thx, as I do not have access to Mathematica at the moment.