# Plotting the InterpolatingFunction from NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, interpolation

I want to plot the solution of a differential equation which i solve it numerically with NDSolve. Here's the code:

```
A := 2.23818*^8;
Zh := 1*^11;
a := 1.496*^11;
M := 1.33*^20;
NDSolve[{(1 + (4 A t^2)/(r[t]^2 (r[t]^2 - Zh^2)) + 
   Zh^2/(r[t]^2 - Zh^2) + (4 A Zh^4 t^2)/(
   r[t]^2 (r[t]^2 - Zh^2)^3) + (8 A Zh^2 t^2)/(
   r[t]^2 (r[t]^2 - Zh^2)^2))*
 r'[t]^2 + ((-4 A t)/(r[t] (r[t]^2 - Zh^2)) - (4 A Zh^2 t)/(
   r[t] (r[t]^2 - Zh^2)^2)) r'[t] + A/(r[t]^2 - Zh^2) - (2 M)/
r[t] + M/a == 0, r[0] == 1.496*^11}, r, {t, 0, 3.15*^5}]
```

And mathematica answers:

```
{{r->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,`, 315000.`}},<>]},{r->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,`, 315000.`}},<>]}
```

I want to plot the answer as a function of "t". what is the code?

Comment: `Plot[r[t] /. %, {t, 0, 3*10^5}]`

Comment: See the first two codes under "Basic Examples" of [the docs for `NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html).

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(63731)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63731), [(66252)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66252). Also related: [(108236)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108236)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot multiple solutions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66534/plot-multiple-solutions)

Comment: I don't think it is quite a duplicate. I think it has value to show how to take the output of `NDsolve` and make a function (or functions) that can be used in downstream processing. I would vote to retain this question and I find m_goldberg's answer particularly helpful. I like alternatives to replacing using the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it.

```
With[{A = 2.23818*^8, Zh = 1*^11, a = 1.496*^11, M = 1.33*^20},
  {rLo, rHi} = 
    NDSolve[
      {(1 + 
         (4 A t^2)/(r[t]^2 (r[t]^2 - Zh^2)) + Zh^2/(r[t]^2 - Zh^2) + 
         (4 A Zh^4 t^2)/(r[t]^2 (r[t]^2 - Zh^2)^3) + 
         (8 A Zh^2 t^2)/(r[t]^2 (r[t]^2 - Zh^2)^2)) r'[t]^2 + 
        ((-4 A t)/(r[t] (r[t]^2 - Zh^2)) - (4 A Zh^2 t) /
          (r[t] (r[t]^2 - Zh^2)^2)) r'[t] + 
        A/(r[t]^2 - Zh^2) - (2 M)/r[t] + M/a == 0, 
       r[0] == 1.496*^11},
      r, {t, 0, 3.15*^5}][[All, 1, 2]]];

Plot[{rHi[t], rLo[t]}, {t, 0, 3.15*^5}]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** If you use `r[t]` instead of `r` as the second argument of `NDSolve` you get the desired functions directly:

```
sol2 = NDSolve[{(1 + (4 A t^2)/(r[t]^2 (r[t]^2 - Zh^2)) +  Zh^2/(r[t]^2 - Zh^2) + 
       (4 A Zh^4 t^2)/(r[t]^2 (r[t]^2 - Zh^2)^3) + 
       (8 A Zh^2 t^2)/(r[t]^2 (r[t]^2 - Zh^2)^2))* r'[t]^2 + 
       ((-4 A t)/(r[t] (r[t]^2 - Zh^2)) - 
       (4 A Zh^2 t)/(r[t] (r[t]^2 - Zh^2)^2)) r'[t] + 
       A/(r[t]^2 - Zh^2) - (2 M)/r[t] + M/a == 0, r[0] == 1.496*^11}, 
    r[t], {t, 0, 3.15*^5}];

funcs2 = r[t] /. sol2
```

> > {InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 315000.}}, <>][t], InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 315000.}}, <>][t]}

So you can use `funcs2` directly when plotting:

```
Plot[funcs2, {t, 0, 3.15*^5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Original post:**

```
ClearAll[r, t, A, Zh, a, M]
A = 2.23818*^8;
Zh = 1*^11;
a = 1.496*^11;
M = 1.33*^20;
sol = NDSolve[{(1 + (4 A t^2)/(r[t]^2 (r[t]^2 - Zh^2)) +  Zh^2/(r[t]^2 - Zh^2) + 
       (4 A Zh^4 t^2)/(r[t]^2 (r[t]^2 - Zh^2)^3) + 
       (8 A Zh^2 t^2)/(r[t]^2 (r[t]^2 - Zh^2)^2))* r'[t]^2 + 
       ((-4 A t)/(r[t] (r[t]^2 - Zh^2)) - 
       (4 A Zh^2 t)/(r[t] (r[t]^2 - Zh^2)^2)) r'[t] + 
       A/(r[t]^2 - Zh^2) - (2 M)/r[t] + M/a == 0, r[0] == 1.496*^11}, 
    r, {t, 0, 3.15*^5}];

funcs = r /. sol;

Plot[Evaluate[Through@funcs@t], {t, 0, 3.15*^5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How it works:

`funcs` is a list of two pure functions:

```
funcs
```

> {InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 315000.}}, <>], InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 315000.}},<>]}

```
funcs[t]
```

> {InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 315000.}}, <>], InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 315000.}},<>]}[t]

We need to push the argument `t` inside the `{..}` to to get the functions we need to plot. This can be done in a number of ways:

```
r[t] /. sol
```

or

```
{funcs[[1]][t], funcs[[2]][t]}
```

or

```
#[t] & /@ funcs
```

or

```
Through[funcs[t]]
```

all give

> {InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 315000.}}, <>][t], InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 315000.}}, <>][t]}